# How to force preview mode?

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks, acf-gutenberg

I have some custom blocks set up using Gutenberg and ACF. I am using the block.json method.

This is part of the block.json file that tells it whether to render as Preview, edit or auto.

```json
  "acf": {
    "mode": "preview",
    "renderTemplate": "hero.php"
  },
```

It does show the Preview, however if I select 'Edit' to show the fields and then press 'Update' on the page, when I return to that page it's showing me in Edit mode. Is it possible to force the page to show you Preview mode whenever you visit it?

Comment: Also have this issue. The best solution so far is to use 'mode' => 'auto'